# Azure Function App error " remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a azure function app which is reading a file. It returns the following error:

> remote name could not be resolved

Code is just this like:

```
byte[] attachmentContent = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("https://www.example.com/Document?Seqn=588736&Ikey=DF466F2A-FD14-4C48-A3E2-5E692E2EF4C9&Aseqn=1764453&noleft=1");
```

Edit: 
1. I can open url in browser and it starts downloading it.
2. Running locally it works fine.

Help please

Comment: Try to open the URL in your computer WebBrowser and see if this succeeds.

Comment: @Tony I can open in browser and it starts downloading file :(

Comment: Is the URL this exact `https://www.example.com/Document?Seqn=588736&Ikey=DF466F2A-FD14-4C48-A3E2-5E692E2EF4C9&Aseqn=1764453&noleft=1`  ?

Comment: Try with another URL, like `"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz7WpA2ISizN-5ms0RZs9wA/?sub_confirmation=1"` I tested here and your code works with another URL.

Comment: Here this URL ( acnc.gov....) worked. Returned a `{byte[155267]}`

Comment: it work locally but in azure it throws error

Comment: Is it Azure Functions v1 or v2?

Comment: Put the complete code. Maybe the problem is another line. I tested this line here and it worked OK.

Comment: are you able to download file please ?

Comment: Yes, worked fine here. Did you click the link I put? See, it downloads the file in the function and return a json with the file lenght.

Comment: also will there be difference of setting between functions and api ? I m using Function v1.

Comment: V1 has different way to return response. Please post the code of this function on this question.

Comment: @Tony it is very long code but this line has error, so now in a new function I m testing only this line with try catch.

Comment: Please try to download the same file via `curl` (or just `nslookup`) from your Function App's Kudu Console. This way, you remove Azure Functions from the equation. See [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues).

Comment: @DavidEbbo tried curl with domain, got a few errors and top was similar "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.example.com'

Comment: So it's done DNS resolution issue. Do you get the same for any other domain, or just the one you're using?

Comment: @DavidEbbo just with this one but strange is locally it works fine. DNS resolution is about server I m accessing right ?

Comment: As a test, try both `nslookup example.com` and `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8` (the second one uses a different DNS server). But you'll need to share the specific domain name for further investigation (or open support case).

Comment: Can you download the file using a private window? Isn't there any authentication/redirect in place?